# how can i formating text with vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Hi i wanna try to formate text to break line after ***
this is only part of the script i think the problem is on computed part maybe i wrote something wrong i have already tried this:

```
<div v-html="post.case_history"></div>
```

and this:

```
computed() {
    post.case_history.replace('***', '<br>')
  }
```

I got this error

> Invalid value for option "computed": expected an Object, but got Function.

Comment: `computed` should be an object...

Answer (score 2):

```
 computed: {
       postCased: function() {
        return this.post.case_history.replace('***', '<br>')
        }
      }
```

-

```
<div v-html="postCased"></div>
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zmvjxB)

Comment: now i have this error:Invalid value for option "computed": expected an Object, but got Function.  and Error in render: "ReferenceError: post is not defined"

Comment: ok perfect but the text that i have change evretime only the *** are same how can change this

Comment: @sofiane could you explain that a bit more? what text and why is it different and what you wanna do with the text etc....?

Comment: ok the text have more then 50 line and if i put break each time where is the star then it will be easy to understand the content the text change each timethat we take other cases  but every text on each cases  have the stars ***

Comment: @sofiane sorry im not sure if im just too dumb but i dont understand the current problem ^^

Comment: :-) no problem on you example you put this  {case_history: "This is *** awesome"}

Comment: how can i change the  "This is *** awesome" with 50 line :-)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks lot i have found the solution:

```
<div v-html="history(post)"></div>


methods: {
    history(post) {
        return post.case_history.replace('***', '<br>') . replace(/\*\*\*/g, '<br>').replace(/------------------------------/g, '<br>');
    }
}
```